# Format original Windows 8 OS and setup dual OS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot

I have original windows 8 OS in my system. Now I just want to format my system. I need it to be fresh as when I freshly installed it as when I bought it with OS, and also need to setup dual boot option with ubuntu OS.

So now if I format the system, how can I get original windows OS.

I am bit confused. I just need to format my system and setup a dual boot.
Can someone tell me some steps to follow to achieve this.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, the OS came with the system inbuilt, I have the product key.

Comment: Then grab a Windows 8 iso and make a bootable device and install it. All data will be removed if you format full drive.